# Disable a single JS event on a specific page?

Tags: javascript

I added a JS script to my footer template before the closing body tag so the code is present on all my pages.

Is there a way to disable this ONE (not all JS) script on specific pages?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script>
  ulp_add_event("onload", {
  popup:        "iP5vHdfUaGgeZ247",
  mode:     "once-period",
  period:       90,
  delay:        2,
  close_delay:  0
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can declare a boolean variable in each page's header section. You can check that boolean value before executing this script in footer template.

Comment: or he can just check in which page he's in before load the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict this in client side the easiest and fastest way I can think of is:

```
<script>
  if(window.location.href !== "YOUR_EXCLUDE_FULL_URL"){
    ulp_add_event("onload", {
      popup:        "iP5vHdfUaGgeZ247",
      mode:     "once-period",
      period:       90,
      delay:        2,
      close_delay:  0
    });
  }

</script>
```

you can also use window.location.pathname and not provide the host and protocol prefix.

if you want something more generic to support multiple exclude pages you can create an array of addresses and the code should look:

```
<script>
  var addressesScriptIsNotLoaded = [
    'ADDRESS_ONE',
    'ADDRESS_TWO'
  ];

  if(addressesScriptIsNotLoaded.indexOf(window.location.href) === -1){
    ulp_add_event("onload", {
      popup:        "iP5vHdfUaGgeZ247",
      mode:     "once-period",
      period:       90,
      delay:        2,
      close_delay:  0
    });
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windowlocation object and an if statement. (There may be a better way)

```
if(window.location.href = 'example.com/mypage'){
dothis()
}
else{

}
```